# gzip: Inflate float array in java

Tags: java, gzip

I am trying to figure out a way to inflate/deflate an array of floats in java.

My code to deflate looks like this, which seems to work fine.

```
List<Float> floats = ...;

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
GZIPOutputStream gzipOut = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(gzipOut);
objectOut.writeObject(floats.toArray(new Float[0]));

return baos.toByteArray();
```

I am having issues with inflating the byte array again back to a float[] array.

Below is one of my attempts, which fails (it even generates NaN floats)

```
byte[] bytes =....
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
GZIPInputStream gzipIn = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(gzipIn);
List<Float> floats = new ArrayList<>()

byte[] buffer = new byte[4]

while (gzipIn.read(buffer) >= 0) {
    Float f  = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer).float
    floats.add(f)
}
return floats
```

I am be able to use any other classes - I just am not able to block as this would be running inside a non blocking event driven server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using different calls - you're calling `writeObject` in the writing part, then assuming that you can just read 4 bytes at a time in the reading part.

Why not just use:

```
Float[] floats = (Float[]) objectIn.readObject();
```

? That would match your writing code. You can then wrap the array in a list if you want to.

Comment: thanks. Well, this is a little embarrassing. So readObject returns the whole inflated data...? That makes everything a lot easier. Just one little thing: I guess you meant to write `Float[] floats = (Float[]) objectIn.readObject();`

Comment: @SteveHummingbird: Yes, that's right. (I've fixed the typo, thanks.) Basically, whenever you've got chained streams like this, there should be symmetry in terms of how you construct them and how you read/write.